# How to create warn on unsaved changes, when user wants to close tab

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to create warn on unsaved changes (it does not matter whether the user has changed the value of the item or not) when user wants to close tab in browser and leave application.

On that page I have items and save button.

Answer (score 1):

What Apex offers as a standard functionality, is to warn users when they are leaving the page (which is **not** closing a tab or a window in their browser!) which has unsaved changes. It is located in Page properties, under the "Navigation" set of properties and is called exactly like that:

> Warn on unsaved changes

---

If you want to capture a tab (or a window) closing operation, there's nothing like that *within Apex*. But, you can check

- what [this blog](http://applicationxpress.blogspot.com/2011/08/warn-user-before-closing-browser-window.html) says about it (author seems to be *unknown*), or
- Skillbuilders [plugins](https://skillbuilders.com/apex-plugins/) page. Sadly, similarly to quite a lot of plugins that work in one version and are never updated to work with newer Apex versions, you'll see two such (deprecated, I mean) plugins for Apex 4.x. You didn't mention which version of Apex you use; if you're still on that *ancient* version, maybe it'll help.

Comment: I want to warn user only when try to close the tab. I use apex 20.1. I tried with an example from the blog you posted, the problem is when I click the button I also get warning.